# Fractional coordinates newtype

Tags: haskell, newtype

I'm making some basic modules about 2D geometry and I've decided to wrap coordinates in newtypes. This is so I can tell easily apart cartesian coordinates (`newtype Xy = Xy(Float,Float)`) from polar coordinates (`newtype Ra=Ra(Float,Float)`), perhaps also complex numbers; also to make them instances of `Num` and `Fractional` so I can overload operators.

But do they have to be defined either as a pair of `Float`s or as pair of `Double`s? In some trigonometric functions, `Double`s might work noticeably better in terms of precision; many of the functions I'm writing for the `Xy` newtype I'd like them to be as generic as possible. 
So is there a way to make a newtype with a pair of numbers of the `Fractional` class?

Also, since I find it a bit cumbersome to write `Xy (0,0)` instead of simply `(0,0)`, I made the `·` operator:

```
(·) a b = Xy (a,b)
```

But it seems to have precedence over the rest, so `3+4·2+1` is evaluated as `3+(Xy (4,2))+1`.
And neither does it help with function declarations, lambda expressions, etc... I still have to write `\Xy (a,b)->`.

Thanks.

Comment: As for the `·` operator (which really belongs in a separate question) – you need a _fixity declaration_, e.g. `infixl 7 ·` (that's what the equivalent `^&` operator in [the `diagrams` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.3.1.3/docs/Diagrams-Coordinates.html#v:-94--38-) uses).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a type parameter in your newtype:

```
newtype Xy n = Xy (n, n)
```

Then you can write functions that work on pairs of anything in the `Fractional` class:

```
foo :: Fractional n => Xy n -> Xy n -> ...
```

You can also use specific types like `Xy Double` if you have operations that only make sense for doubles.

Unfortunately, you can't just reuse the tuple syntax (`(a, b)`), but it's manageable if you write a type that has two fields instead of wrapping a pair:

```
data Xy n = Xy n n
```

Now you can just write `Xy a b` as a value or a pattern. You can even make it a record to get convenient field syntax:

```
data Xy n = Xy { x, y :: n }
```

This works just like the previous version but *also* allows you to use `x` and `y` as functions (ie `x :: Xy n -> n`) and in patterns.

Comment: Thanks Tikhon. 
Data types are surely cleaner looking (plus other advantages), but it is my understanding that they slow performance a bit because of the wrapping and unwrapping, unlike newtypes. Coordinates are something basic that comes in big numbers when defining things like smooth curves, so worrying in advance I chose newtypes.

Comment: @AsíMaullóJosetustra A `newtype` is _represented in the same way_ as the type it wraps. So `newtype Xy n = Xy (n, n)` appears the same at runtime as `(n,n)` Here's the important part: **`(n,n)` is itself a datatype**. In fact the in-memory representation of `(n,n)` happens to be the same as the representation of `data Xy n = Xy n n` (a pointer to a thunk containing a pair of pointers). So your `newtype` version is just the same as @TikhonJelvis's `data` suggestion. The only time the `newtype` costs less is when you're converting to or from a tuple.

Comment: Oh, this does change things! I'll be using data then, since it also has some other advantages. Thanks for clarifying that!

Answer (score 3):

IMO you should probably just use `Double`, always and hard-baked. On an x86-64 processor, there's no real advantage that `Float` would give you – it takes the same memory (as each value needs a 64-bit pointer to refer to it anyway), is no faster (could even require extra alignment overhead) – there's just no point. `Double` is fine, it's fast and the best precision you can usually strive for<sup>†</sup>.

It's certainly *much* better than if you stored, OO-like, a generic instance of the fractional class – this kind of polymorphism causes quite a heavy overload. Fortunately, Haskell also really eschews [storing polymorphic values](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type).

I also don't consider it conceptually sensible to define `Xy` as a functor, i.e. a type that *parametrically* polymorphic over the coordinate type, as suggested by [Tikhon Jelvis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38510507/745903). While this is absolutely a valid approach and can give really good performance (it's how the [linear library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) works), this misses what vectors are about. A mathematical vector is foremostly *not* a tuple of numbers, but [a quantity that has both a direction and a magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)). The actual *coordinates* of such a vector should be considered only an implementation detail.

You also don't want to make those 2D-things instances of the `Num` etc. classes. Those classes are for [numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) – quantities that can canonically be added, subtracted *and multiplied*. You can't multiply vectors though, at least not in a way that should give you again a vector. The correct class for vectors is [`VectorSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#t:VectorSpace), not `Num`.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>It should be noted that [packed](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed-Mutable.html#t:Unbox) `Float` arrays do save lots of memory, and if you use modern [vectorised processor instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4) they can also be effectively much faster. But these are optimisations that aren't really accessible at the level where you're talking about single tuples.</sub>